# JHipster not throwing errors to UI when microservice fails

Tags: mongodb, jhipster, microservices, consul

We are running JHipster microservice architecture using consul for service discovery. We have one micro service which connects to a docker instance of mongodb. While testing with the stock angular ui to save a new entity, we found that disabling the database does not throw an error in the UI. From the consul ui, I can see that the service is failing 1 of 2 health checks which will pass again when I re-enable the db.

In the gateway logs, I have the following:
`Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: import`

I assume that consul is refusing to make the service available to gateway, but it seems there should be some way to configure  how gateway handles requests to unavailable services. Can anyone tell me where to look for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. The gateway will only route requests to services that pass all consul healthchecks.

Note that by default Spring Boot automatically configure a healtcheck for your database. It is located at the  /management/health endpoint of your microservice.

You could configure Consul health checks with the spring.cloud.consul keys of your microservice. I don't remember the specific ones but if you use IDEA it will autocomplete the available properties...

Comment: Thank you for your response Pierre. I am trying to determine how to handle a scenario where a requested service is not available. By default, the gateway sends 200 back to the UI, even though the request has not been fulfilled. I would prefer to send back a response stating that the service is unavailable, but I do not know where to set that.

Comment: @thejames42 This is caused by Hystrix which automatically "open the circuit" hence respond with 200's. This can be customized to suit your needs. See for example: https://www.google.fr/amp/s/jmnarloch.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/spring-cloud-zuul-error-handling/amp/?client=ms-android-oneplus

Comment: Not sure how to mark this as the answer, so marking the parent. Thanks!